# How to read and save Switch data with Datastore in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How to read and save Switch data with Datastore in Jetpack Compose? I need to store current state in datastore and load state when app is closed and opened again by user.

```
class DataStoreUtil(private val context: Context) {

    companion object {
        private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore("settings")
        val FORCE_DARK_THEME = booleanPreferencesKey("force_dark_theme")
    }

    val getForceDarkTheme: Flow<Boolean> = context.dataStore.data
        .map { preferences ->
            preferences[FORCE_DARK_THEME] ?: true
        }

    suspend fun saveForceDarkTheme(value: Boolean) {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[FORCE_DARK_THEME] = value
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MySwitch() {
    val checkedState = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Switch(
        checked = checkedState.value,
        onCheckedChange = { checkedState.value = it }
    )
    Text(
        text = if(checkedState.value) "foo" else "bar",
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class DataStoreUtil(private val context: Context) {

    companion object {
        private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore("settings")
        val FORCE_DARK_THEME = booleanPreferencesKey("force_dark_theme")
    }

    val getForceDarkTheme: Flow<Boolean> = context.dataStore.data
        .map { preferences ->
            preferences[FORCE_DARK_THEME] ?: true
        }

    suspend fun saveForceDarkTheme(value: Boolean) {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[FORCE_DARK_THEME] = value
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MySwitch() {

   val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
   //creating an object of your datastore
    val dataStore = DataStoreUtil(LocalContext.current)
   //retrieving the boolean value from the data store as a state
    val switchState by dataStore.getForceDarkTheme.collectAsState()

    Switch(
        checked = switchState,
        onCheckedChange = {
scope.launch{
 dataStore.saveForceDarkTheme(it) 
}
}
    )
    Text(
        text = if(checkedState.value) "foo" else "bar",
    )
}
```

To use collectAsState with the Flow value you must add this dependency in the build.gradle file

```
  implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.6.0-beta01")
```

Comment: It gives error "Suspend function 'saveForceDarkTheme' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function"

Comment: @Jorpy try with the edit

Comment: I would initial state be false. I changed it to false in CollectAsState() but it always return true.

Comment: @Jorpy that's because you're returning true in the DataStoreUtil class, so for the very first time when there is nothing saved in the datastore it will return true. Change the else part of elvis operator to false, so that it would return false for the very first time.